# Checking to see if a range of ports is open or not in Windows 10

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, remote-desktop, port

I installed `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` and I get the following when I enter `netstat -atn`. I am now sure why it doesn't output anything.

```
mona@DESKTOP-37GGNHL:~$ netstat -atn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
```

I need to make sure my machine follows the rules as this document regarding open ports:

> RenderDoc uses TCP and UDP ports 38920-38927 consecutively for remote
>   access and control (ie. capturing remotely) for each new program that
>   is opened on a machine. Note that even if you initiate a capture
>   locally these ports are still opened for listening. These are the
>   ports that are probed on a remote host to see if a connection exists.
>
> RenderDoc also uses TCP and UDP ports 39920 for remote replay
>   connections, for when a remote host is used to replay and analyse the
>   log.

I get this result for `netstat -atn` in cmd:

```
C:\Users\mona>netstat -atn

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           Offload State

  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1536           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1537           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1538           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1539           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1540           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1546           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:57621          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:139     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1550    65.52.108.191:443      ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1568    65.52.108.203:443      ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1579    205.213.108.151:443    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1580    205.213.108.157:443    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1593    209.85.147.188:5228    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1600    205.213.108.147:443    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1624    157.56.52.17:40015     CLOSE_WAIT      InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1628    91.190.218.66:12350    CLOSE_WAIT      InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1649    193.235.32.146:4070    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1770    205.213.108.151:443    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1847    192.30.253.124:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1917    205.213.114.185:80     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1945    151.101.65.69:443      ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1987    198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:1994    198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2100    192.186.157.43:6667    ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2125    104.20.111.39:443      ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2162    104.20.7.245:443       ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2207    104.16.97.40:443       ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2208    151.101.45.140:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2245    151.101.65.69:80       ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2265    216.58.216.202:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2288    151.101.1.69:80        ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2292    151.101.1.69:80        ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2310    172.217.4.102:443      ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2311    151.101.65.69:80       ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2313    23.222.196.138:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2321    198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2322    151.101.65.69:80       ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2325    23.222.193.111:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2326    64.4.54.253:443        ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2330    209.95.38.214:443      TIME_WAIT       InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2333    204.79.197.200:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2334    204.79.197.200:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2335    216.58.193.131:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:2336    204.79.197.200:443     ESTABLISHED     InHost
  TCP    10.140.235.155:33659   0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4370         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4371         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4380         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4381         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9990         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:22                [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:1536              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:1537              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:1538              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:1539              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:1540              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:1546              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::1]:1721             [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3544           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5050           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:49664          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:49678          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:49679          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:52881          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:54931          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:57621          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:58254          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:61946          *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:61947          *:*
  UDP    10.140.235.155:137     *:*
  UDP    10.140.235.155:138     *:*
  UDP    10.140.235.155:1900    *:*
  UDP    10.140.235.155:5353    *:*
  UDP    10.140.235.155:33659   *:*
  UDP    10.140.235.155:49675   *:*
  UDP    10.140.235.155:52882   *:*
  UDP    10.140.235.155:64166   *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:48200        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:48201        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49666        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49667        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49668        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49669        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49670        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:49676        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59881        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59882        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59883        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59884        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59885        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59886        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59887        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59888        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:62712        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:63911        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:63912        *:*
  UDP    127.0.0.1:65000        *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
  UDP    [::]:49665             *:*
  UDP    [::]:52881             *:*
  UDP    [::]:61947             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:5353             *:*
  UDP    [::1]:49674            *:*
  UDP    [fe80::7449:2c48:9a7b:e1ab%7]:1900  *:*
  UDP    [fe80::7449:2c48:9a7b:e1ab%7]:49673  *:*
```

Basically what's the command for checking the port range between two integer numbers?

How can I open TCP and UDP ports 38920-38927 consecutively?

Comment: When you do the `netstat`, is RenderDoc running, and configured to accept connections?   Ordinarily, one doesn't have to take steps to open a port on a local machine; the program does that as part of it's networking code.  The paragraph quoted seems like it's of an FYI nature, or for configuring network access on routers/firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for a guide to opening tcp and udp sockets under Bash:

http://xmodulo.com/tcp-udp-socket-bash-shell.html